# loading static data into nested struct in Go

Tags: json, go, struct

I am looking to implement something very similar to this GoPlayground example:
https://go.dev/play/p/B4JOVwgdwUk

However my data structure is a bit more complex, with the nested struct called Tag. I can't quite get the syntax correct for how to load the data into the struct in the `toFile` variable declaration.

Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?  I have tried what is displayed in the full code below, as well as this:

```
Tags:        []Tag{
            [{"appID:": "go", "category": "backend"},{"appID": "fiber", "category": "framework"}]
        }
```

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    type Stack struct {
        Reputation   int    `json:"reputation"`
        UserID       int    `json:"user_id"`
        UserType     string `json:"user_type"`
        ProfileImage string `json:"profile_image"`
        DisplayName  string `json:"display_name"`
        Link         string `json:"link"`
        Tags         []Tag  `json:"tags"`
    }
    type Tag struct {
        AppID           string `json: "appID:,omitempty"`
        Category    string  `json: "category:,omitempty"`
    }
    toFile := Stack{
        Reputation:   141,
      UserID:       9820773,
      UserType:     "registered",
      ProfileImage: "https://graph.facebook.com/10209865263541884/picture?type=large",
      DisplayName:  "Joe Smith",
      Link:         "https://stackoverflow.com/users/9820773/joe-smith",
      Tags:        Tag{
            [{"appID:": "go", "category": "backend"},{"appID": "fiber", "category": "framework"}] 
        } // cannot get this to work
  }
    
    // Write it out!
    tmpFile, err := ioutil.TempFile(os.TempDir(), "sample-")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer os.Remove(tmpFile.Name())
    err = json.NewEncoder(tmpFile).Encode(toFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Let's read it in!
    tmpFile2, err := os.Open(tmpFile.Name())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var fromFile Person
    err = json.NewDecoder(tmpFile2).Decode(&fromFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpFile2.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", fromFile)
}
```

Comment: you should be using struct literal not a map syntax. something like this https://go.dev/play/p/EioytQ6zj0B

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @Kousik helped me fix up the code and run it successfully on the GoPlayground:
https://go.dev/play/p/WmZ9m_55W3S

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    type Tag struct {
        AppID    string `json: "appID:,omitempty"`
        Category string `json: "category:,omitempty"`
    }

    type Stack struct {
        Reputation   int    `json:"reputation"`
        UserID       int    `json:"user_id"`
        UserType     string `json:"user_type"`
        ProfileImage string `json:"profile_image"`
        DisplayName  string `json:"display_name"`
        Link         string `json:"link"`
        Tags         []Tag  `json:"tags"`
    }

    toFile := Stack{
        Reputation:   141,
        UserID:       9820773,
        UserType:     "registered",
        ProfileImage: "https://graph.facebook.com/10209865263541884/picture?type=large",
        DisplayName:  "Joe Smith",
        Link:         "https://stackoverflow.com/users/9820773/joe-smith",
        Tags:         []Tag{{AppID: "id1", Category: "cat1"}, {AppID: "id2", Category: "cat2"}},
    }

    // Write it out!
    tmpFile, err := ioutil.TempFile(os.TempDir(), "sample-")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer os.Remove(tmpFile.Name())
    err = json.NewEncoder(tmpFile).Encode(toFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpFile.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Let's read it in!
    tmpFile2, err := os.Open(tmpFile.Name())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var fromFile Stack
    err = json.NewDecoder(tmpFile2).Decode(&fromFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = tmpFile2.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", fromFile)
}
```